# Mounting fileshare on Azure Linux machine using VM Run Command through Bicep

Tags: azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine, azure-bicep

I am trying to mount fileshare on Azure Linux machine using VM Run Command through Bicep. The deployment gets success but mount point did not get create. Below is the bicep config. Here storage account and VM is in different resource group

```
  resource vm 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines@2021-03-01' existing = {
    name: 'rabolinuxvm'
  }

  resource customextensionscript 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/runCommands@2022-11- 
   01' = {
   name: 'samount'
   parent: vm
   location: 'eastus'
   properties: {
     source: {
       script: ''' 
       sudo mkdir /etc/share3                
       credentialRoot="/etc/smbcredentials"
       sudo mkdir -p "/etc/smbcredentials"
       storageAccountKey=$(az storage account keys list \
         --resource-group $resourceGroupName \
         --account-name $storageAccountName \
         --query "[0].value" --output tsv | tr -d '"')

       smbCredentialFile="$credentialRoot/$storageAccountName.cred"

       if [ ! -f $smbCredentialFile ]; then
          echo "username=$storageAccountName" | sudo tee $smbCredentialFile > /dev/null
          echo "password=$storageAccountKey" | sudo tee -a $smbCredentialFile > 
            /dev/null
       else
         echo "The credential file $smbCredentialFile already exists, and was not 
         modified."
       fi

       sudo chmod 600 $smbCredentialFile
       fileShareName="share4" 
       mntPath="/etc/$fileShareName"
       sudo mkdir -p $mntPath
       httpEndpoint=$(az storage account show \
         --resource-group $resourceGroupName \
         --name $storageAccountName \
         --query "primaryEndpoints.file" --output tsv | tr -d '"')

       smbPath=$(echo $httpEndpoint | cut -c7-${#httpEndpoint})$fileShareName

      if [ -z "$(grep $smbPath\ $mntPath /etc/fstab)" ]; then
         echo "$smbPath $mntPath cifs 
            nofail,credentials=$smbCredentialFile,serverino,nosharesock,actimeo=30" | 
            sudo tee -a /etc/fstab > /dev/null
      else
        echo "/etc/fstab was not modified to avoid conflicting entries as this Azure 
        file share was already present. You may want to double check /etc/fstab to 
        ensure the configuration is as desired."
      fi
      sudo mount -a  '''        


     }
    }
```

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: Have you check the troubleshooting section of the documentation ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/run-command#action-run-command-linux-troubleshooting

Comment: HI Thomas, i would see below error log in stderr file////

/var/lib/waagent/run-command-handler/download/samount/8/script.sh: line 9: --resource-group: command not found
/var/lib/waagent/run-command-handler/download/samount/8/script.sh: line 10: --account-name: command not found
/var/lib/waagent/run-command-handler/download/samount/8/script.sh: line 11: --query: command not found
/var/lib/waagent/run-command-handler/download/samount/8/script.sh: line 9: $'\r': command not found
/var/lib/waagent/run-command-handler/download/samount/8/script.sh: line 11: $'\r': command not found

Comment: oh ok, looks like indentation issue. so you have this line `script: ''' ` then you idented all your script content. can you remove the extra spaces at the beginning of the lines and see how that goes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I tried in my environment and got the below results:**

You can use the below scripts to mount the file share to Azure Linux VM:

**Test.bicep**

```
resource vm 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines@2021-03-01' existing = {
  name: 'venkatlinux'
}

resource customextensionscript 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/runCommands@2022-11-01' = {
 name: 'venkat1'
 parent: vm
 location: 'eastus'
 properties: {
   source: {
     script: ''' 
     sudo mkdir /mnt/venkat
if [ ! -d "/etc/smbcredentials" ]; then
sudo mkdir /etc/smbcredentials
fi
if [ ! -f "/etc/smbcredentials/saibabatest123.cred" ]; then
    sudo bash -c 'echo "username=saibabatest123" >> /etc/smbcredentials/saibabatest123.cred'
    sudo bash -c 'echo "password="" >> /etc/smbcredentials/saibabatest123.cred'
fi
sudo chmod 600 /etc/smbcredentials/saibabatest123.cred

sudo bash -c 'echo "//saibabatest123.file.core.windows.net/venkat /mnt/venkat cifs nofail,credentials=/etc/smbcredentials/saibabatest123.cred,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,serverino,nosharesock,actimeo=30" >> /etc/fstab'
sudo mount -t cifs //saibabatest123.file.core.windows.net/venkat /mnt/venkat -o credentials=/etc/smbcredentials/saibabatest123.cred,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,serverino,nosharesock,actimeo=30 '''        

   }
  }
}
```

You can get the script section from the portal:

Storage accounts -> your storage account -> file share ->connect-> linux -> select script &copy and paste it like above in your bicep file.

[image]

**Deployments:**

```
DeploymentName          : test
ResourceGroupName       : your resource grp name
ProvisioningState       : Succeeded
Timestamp               : 3/28/2023 6:41:29 AM
Mode                    : Incremental
TemplateLink            : 
Parameters              : 
Outputs                 : 
DeploymentDebugLogLevel :
```

[image]

To check the file share is mounted with Linux virtual machine you can use the below command:

**Command:**

```
df-h
```

**Output:**

The below screenshots tell that it was successfully mounted to your Linux VM.

[image]

If you need to check files inside the file share you can use the command

```
cd /mnt/your file share name
ls
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: thanks Venkat, but how you are passing storage account key here , i see it is empty. how that would get connected

Comment: I mentioned in the above screenshots how to get the script please check them. In that script, it has an account name and password.

Comment: echo "password="" >> /etc/smbcredentials/saibabatest123.cred'
 should i keep the key in this doble quotes.  if so i would like to do it dynamically

Comment: Password is your storage account key you need to pass there.

Comment: so can't we include this in the script 
storageAccountKey='$(az storage account keys list \
        --resource-group sample1-rg \
        --account-name rabostorage123 \
        --query "[0].value" --output tsv | tr -d '"')'

Comment: Yes, you don't need to include that script.

Comment: i need to get the key dynamically and donot want hard code or provide it manually to the script. becuase same script need to run for multiple environments. could you please help if we can include it in the script

Comment: According to your error, you need to pass your storage account name and resource grp name.

Comment: i tried to run your code but mount point is like mkdir /etc/share6, so it created folder like /etc/'share6'$'\r'  and failed with below error.  why folder not created like share6   and what i am missing for the below error, i ensure no space at the last line (no 12)
./script.sh: line 13: syntax error: unexpected end of file